# Default items in WooCommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have just 3 products in WooCommerce and need to display them all in cart regardless of whether or not they have been added. 
So i tried to add items to cart by default using the code below. It works ok in case when quantity more than 0, but now i get *cart-empty.php* instead of *cart.php*.

Is there any option to allow WooCommerce add items with `$quantity = 0`? 

Thanks in advance.

```
  add_action( 'template_redirect', 'add_product_to_cart' );
    function add_product_to_cart() {
        if ( ! is_admin() && WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0 ) {
            $product_id = 175;

            $found = false;
            //check if product already in cart
            if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 2 ) {
                foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                    $_product = $values['data'];
                    if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
                        $found = true;
                }
                // if product not found, add it
                if ( ! $found )
                    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity = 0);
        } else {
            // if no products in cart, add it
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity = 0);
        }
}
```

Comment: No that is not possible, as adding a cart item with a **Zero quantity** is just like as doing nothing.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thank you a lot for reply.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Maybe it is possible to disable redirection to cart-empty.php when cart is empty? So i could show items in cart.php via $products object before they would be added.

Comment: I just answer your question in my comment: *"Is there any option to allow WooCommerce add items with $quantity = 0?"* …and the is answer is **"NO way"*.